# Iterate through loops but with reduced first number in second loop,

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

Hello I need to write a pair of loops that would go through numbers in specific way. I'll try to show on example.

lets say I have loops like this.

```
for(let i = 0; let i <4; i++){
for (let j = ?; condition;? ){
console.log(j) 
}
```

and from this I would want result in console like this: 12345 2345 345 45 (but numbers printed in console indivudally not as string)

If it was `i < 3` result should be 1234 234 34 etc.

How would you write the conditions or what would you do to get the result?

Thank you for any help.

Edit: I need the numbers to be printed by console.log as individual number and not a s string, sorry for bad description, same way this code would

```
(let i =0; i<4; i++ )
{ 
console.log(i) 
}
```

Comment: Please show example of your exact result needed line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

```js
for(let i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
  if(i!=4){
    for (let j = i; j<=4;j++){
      console.log(j)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Again, sorry for bad description of the issue, but I need the numbers to be printed individualy, I wrote the comas there just to separate the loops.

Comment: oh okay you like:
1
2
3
4
2
3
4
3
4
4

Comment: try now if you will

Comment: Yes, so the numbers are printed individually. I edited the question so it hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: Almost, I still need it without the last nubmer. So in this case it should be: 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 3 4

Answer (score 0):

A general solution using for-loop.

```js
function ReturnNumberList(n){
   let arrayList=[], base= "";

  //loop to build the base number
   for(let i=1;i<n+1;i++){
       base= base + (i).toString();
      }

  //loop to print the list
   for(let i=0;i<n-1;i++){
      let temp = base.substr(i,base.length);
      console.log(temp)
      arrayList.push(temp);
    }
   return arrayList.join(",").replace(/,/g,"");
}
```